# Restructure hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have an initial hash which has a structure given below

**Initial Hash**

```
initial_hash = {
 `section1`:{
  'person_name1':{
     'city': 'City1',
     'country': 'Country1'
   },
  'person_name2':{
     'city': 'City2',
     'country': 'Country2'
   },
   ...
 },
 `section2`:{
  'person_name12':{
     'city': 'City12',
     'country': 'Country12'
   },
  'person_name23':{
     'city': 'City23',
     'country': 'Country23'
   },
   ...
 }
}
```

**Final Hash**

```
final_hash = {
  `section1`:{
   'country1':{
      'city': 'City1',
      'person_name': 'person_name1'
    },
   'country2':{
      'city': 'City2',
      'person_name': 'person_name2'
    },
    ...
  },
  `section2:{
   'country12':{
      'city': 'City12',
      'person_name': 'person_name12'
    },
   'country23':{
      'city': 'City23',
      'person_name': 'person_name23'
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

As you can see that the `final_hash` has been restructured so as `country` and `person_name` has taken the place of each other. So far my attempt for it is as below:

**My attempt:**

```
final_hash = {}
initial_hash.each do |h|
 final_hash[h[0]] = {}
 final_hash[h[0]] = h[1].group_by{|x| x[1]['country']}.each{|_, v| v.map!{|h| h[1]}}
end
```

The above attempt helps me getting this structure:

```
final_hash = {
  'section1':{
    'country'1: {
      'city': 'City1',
      'country': 'Country1'
     },
     'country2': {
      'city': 'City2',
      'country': 'Country2'
     },
    ...
  },
 'section2':{
    'country'12: {
      'city': 'City12',
      'country': 'Country12'
     },
     'country23': {
      'city': 'City23',
      'country': 'Country23'
     },
    ...
  } 
}
```

I'm not able to understand how to place the `person_name` in place of `country`. I tried to add up `each` to result of `map!` block. But no luck so far. To add to this problem, i have a `json data which consist of 1000 records`, so `performance is a concern here`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is each country in the final hash supposed to be an array of hashes?  Would India, for example, have multiple values in an array?

Comment: no. It will be just a value like this `country: India`

Comment: I see. You mean `initial_hash = {...`, not `initial_hash: {....`, which I read as the key-value pair `:initial_hash=>{...` (as will others).  Please correct that. Note 'person_name': 'Bob' is the same as :'person_name'=>'Bob'. Did you mean that to be `person_name:.`. or `:person_name=>..`?.

Answer (score 1):

try to use inject:

1) only inject for inner hash:

```
initial_hash.inject({}){ |h,(section,inner_hash)| h.merge section => inner_hash.inject({}) { |inner_h,(k,v)| inner_h.merge v.delete(:country) => v.merge(person_name: k) }}
```

2) use map & inject:

```
Hash[initial_hash.map { |section, inner_hash| [section, inner_hash.inject({}) { |inner_h, (k, v)| inner_h.merge v.delete(:country) => v.merge(person_name: k) }]}]
```

benchmark(for 1000):

```
                user     system      total        real

  injects:    0.060000   0.010000   0.070000 (  0.057551)

  map&inject: 0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.053678)
```

Comment: So sorry, actually i missed one level of nesting in that hash. Check the updated question.

Comment: juse use another inject: `initial_hash.inject({}){|h,(section,v)| h.merge section => v.inject....}`

Comment: Can you please correct your answer? I have less understanding of `inject`. Also, if it is right then it would be bad practice to have the right answer in the comments.